# wordpress xmlrpc call wp.editPost making content empty

Tags: javascript, wordpress, xml-rpc

I am working with [wordpress xmlrpc javascript api](https://github.com/developerworks/wordpress-xmlrpc-javascript-api), a neat javascript api for accessing wordpress's xmlrpc api from javascript.

The problem I have is, after `wp.editPost` returns `true`, the post content is simply blank!

This is my relevant code:

```
var wp = new WordPress(blog, username, password);
var blogId = 1;
var object = wp.getPost(blogId, postId);
// alert(JSON.stringify(object));
var currentContent = object.post_content;
alert(currentContent); // works fine
var newContent = currentContent.replace('</ul>', strToInsert + '</ul>')
alert(newContent); // works, and it is what I want the content to be after editing
object = wp.editPost(blogId, postId, {post_content:newContent});
alert(JSON.stringify(object)); // works, alerts true
```

Now, refreshing my **page**, the changes do not take place, but instead my content becomes empty now.

[image: empty content]

Any idea what is wrong? I am sure it has to be something with wordpress. I could look into it but I was wondering if any of you had similar problem too!

Note: I refresh the page while I was logged in. Does this matter anyhow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem, was with `newContent`. It was html, and wordpress didn't like it. I solved it after numerous attempts by escaping `newContent` before it is sent, using [this SO answer's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124052/1273830). And, it works now.

Thanks to @Anentropic.